# tomorrow's + THE NAME OF A DAY

Tags: possessives

Is it acceptable to use this pattern?

**I want to see him on {tomorrow's Monday/Tuesday} so on.**

An example from a book:

> The captain took the opportunity of requesting a supply of Japanese
> Yen to be brought out to the ship that afternoon, and at the same time
> he ordered a shore boat for tomorrow's Sunday.

by Melvin Douglas Smart

Comment: It's certainly unacceptable. I don't even understand what you want it to *mean*. Is tomorrow *actually* Sunday?

Comment: If you mean "not the *first* Sunday after today, but the *next* one after that", then in British English we say *I'll see you **Sunday week*** - which I don't think I've ever encountered from an American.  Also, I personally would never use ***Sunday week*** if today was a Sunday, because it's inherently confusing (7 days from now? Or 14?). But maybe some others might.

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to me, but I wonder if *Sunday* is a reference to something else, like it's a shorthand for "Sunday religious services" or "the regular Sundays on which the crew has shore leave."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use it the way you are trying to.

Regarding your quote, remember that:

- 'apostrophe s' may denote a possessive noun, but can also indicate a contraction with 'is'.
- 'for' can also mean '*because*' (eg "*eat drink and be merry for tomorrow we may die*")

So, your original quote could possibly mean:

> he ordered a shore boat *because tomorrow is Sunday*.

It is difficult to know without the full context of your quotation, but Sunday has historically been a day of no trading, so from it could be that this order for a boat was made because it could not be made the following day.

Either way, "tomorrow's Sunday" is not an idiomatic way of indicating a specific day, at least not in modern English.